# Determining which element was clicked and conditionally choosing which method to call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to use JQuery to make 3 thumbnails into buttons that each open up their own page element with details regarding the picture.

Right now I have succeeded in making it so that any thumbnail causes a page element (of the class "description") to scroll open and closed when any thumbnail (from the class "thumbnail") is clicked.

How do I check which thumbnail is clicked on so that I can open a different description corresponding to that specific thumbnail? (This is what I was attempting to do with the "select").

```
var main = function() {
  $('.thumbnail').click(function(select) {      
    var description = $('.game-descriptions').children('.description');     
    if( description.is(":hidden")) {
        description.slideDown("slow");
    }
    else
        description.hide();    
  });   
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a data attribute to specify what the thumbnail `click` is targeting, example: `data-target="#game-1"`, add IDs to your descriptions that match and use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) to use the attribute value of `#game-1` a jQuery selector.

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6s1g26rg/5)

**JS**

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function() {

    var gameId = $(this).data('target');

    $(gameId).slideToggle().siblings(':visible').slideToggle();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="thumbnail" data-target="#game-1" />    
<img class="thumbnail" data-target="#game-2" />

<div class="game-descriptions">
    <div id="game-1" class="description"></div>
    <div id="game-2" class="description"></div>
</div>
```

Any toggling like `toggle()`, `slideToggle()`, `fadeToggle()` handles the `is hidden` or `is visible`

Comment: Thank you, I used this method and it worked great. I tried altering it so that both descriptions can't show at once but I am having trouble targetting all the descriptions excluding the one clicked.

Comment: I just updated this answer and demo link to also include slideToggle() the visible siblings. Which will hide the other descriptions when a new one is clicked

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry I was so slow to reply, my internet has been out all day, so I'm using my phone to reply. Your demo works exactly how I would like mine to, but that change didnt work for me. On my site, it functioned just as before (toggling without hiding the previously opened description). The only change was the last line of the function, right? Or am I missing something.

Comment: My demo hides the descriptions with css before the jquery acts on them. `.description {display: none;}` try that :)

Comment: I found what it was. It was from the organization of my html. When I added in the 2nd description I had nested it in a separate game-description div. So basically the descriptions weren't actually siblings. I fixed it and it works perfectly now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/c76vqumo/)

The parameter to the click function is a jQuery [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), which can be useful in adding some event handling logic. However, within the context of the handler, `this` refers to the element which triggered the click event, and is typically sufficient for any targeted logic.

Assuming the thumbnails and descriptions have similarly named IDs, for example, you can do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.thumbnail').click(function (event) {
        var descId = this.id.replace("thumb", "desc");
        var description = $('.game-descriptions').children('#' + descId);
        // or simply $("#" + descId);

        description.toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumb-1">Thumb 1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumb-2">Thumb 2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumb-3">Thumb 3</div>
</div>
<div class="game-descriptions">
    <div class="description" id="desc-1">Description One</div>
    <div class="description" id="desc-2">Description Two</div>
    <div class="description" id="desc-3">Description Three</div>
</div>
```

Your technique for targeting the correct 'description' will depend on your actual DOM structure, however.

Also note that I substituted the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method for your `if` statement, as the logic you have is equivalent to what it does (i.e. toggling object visibility).